# Android Custom Camera Image Size

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-custom-view, image-size

I am working on a custom camera application. I have set the camera parameters with optimal image resolution which is resulting in setting maximum resolution. But when I capture the image from my custom camera application the image size generated is smallest supported size by the camera.

The Camera parameters that I have set are 1920*1080
but the image size is 144*176

How we can get proper size image of 1920*1080?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009347/change-camera-resolution-setting-programmatically-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

There is a setPictureSize() method:

```
Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

params.setPictureSize (width, height);

mCamera.setParameters(params);
```